# Manually set wpa_supplicant driver?

Tags: debian, wifi, ssl, wpa-supplicant, wpa2-eap

I'm using a RaspberryPi 4 (4GB) and I was able to set up `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` with all needed certificates properly, to authenticate at our companys wifi:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=US

fast_reauth=1

network={
    ssid="WIFI-Com"
    scan_ssid=1
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP IEEE8021X
    pairwise=CCMP
    group=CCMP
    eap=TLS
    identity="user@domain.com"
    ca_cert="/etc/cert/ca.pem"
    client_cert="/etc/cert/client.pem"
    private_key="/etc/cert/clientkey.pem"
}
```

Using `wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -D wext -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` for testing, it's authenticating perfectly and obtaining a vaild IP:

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
wlan0: Trying to associate with 00:5d:71:c9:4d:ef (SSID='WIFI-Com' freq=5320 MHz)
FT: Invalid group cipher (0)
Failed to add supported operating classes IE
wlan0: Associated with 00:5d:71:c9:4d:ef
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=13
tls_connection_set_params: Clearing pending SSL error: error:14187180:SSL routines:ssl_do_config:bad value
tls_connection_set_params: Clearing pending SSL error: error:14187180:SSL routines:ssl_do_config:bad value
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-METHOD EAP vendor 0 method 13 (TLS) selected
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=1 subject='/DC=com/DC=company/CN=Company Certification Authority' hash=53e1f7164f972fccfa24dc5dee64e362bed56ea014995fd990c760dd873760a7
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PEER-CERT depth=0 subject='/C=COM/L=NewYork/O=Company/CN=eap.comp.com' hash=d586970276d8076bd01cdbd4258452ea291d72af282fefa80fd8f8ef55e0c471
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-SUCCESS EAP authentication completed successfully
wlan0: PMKSA-CACHE-ADDED 00:5d:71:c9:4d:ef 0
wlan0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 00:5d:71:c9:4d:ef [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 00:5d:71:c9:4d:ef completed [id=0 id_str=]

$ ifconfig
wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.128.131.109  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.188.139.255
        inet6 fe80::4665:3320:1509:a176  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether dc:a6:32:2d:3e:e2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4329  bytes 1559945 (1.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 5734  bytes 2019622 (1.9 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

If I reboot the Pi and run `ps auxwww | grep wpa` its supposed to connect to my wifi, as it is using the command given above. But it's not, instead it used driver `nl80211`. From what I experienced, it's only authenticating properly using exclusively `-D wext`. Where can I edit the `-D` parameters, that are used while booting?

```
root       334  ..   0:00 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /run/wpa_supplicant
root       440  ..   0:00 wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -iwlan0 -Dnl80211,wext
pi         721  ..   0:00 grep --color=auto wpa
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of modifying `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks/10-wpa_supplicant` you can just add

```
env wpa_supplicant_driver=wext
```

to the end of `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able figure it out. For some reason it used `nl80211` instead of `wext` and I removed every `nl80211` entry in `/lib/dhcpcd/dhcpcd-hooks/10-wpa_supplicant`.

Pretty special case and maybe not the common way, but done the trick.